# Как создать кэш, чтобы лишний раз не ходить в базу - Хибернейт (hibernate)?

Tags: hibernate, java

Никак не могу написать идеальное решение - хочу создать кэш, чтобы закидывать туда часто вызываемые данные. Например, имеем код:

```
public static List<EntityCity> getCities() {
        Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<EntityCity> list = (List<EntityCity>) session.createQuery("...").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }
```

Вызываю так:

```
 Object fromCache = MyCache.get(MyCacheKeys.ENTITY_CITIES);
 if (fromCache != null) {
     return (List<EntityCity>) fromCache;
 }
```

Класс MyCacheKeys примерно такой:

```
public class SMCacheKeys {
    public static String ENTITY_CITIES = "from EntityCity where active = 'true'";
}
```

Кэш такой:

```
public class MyCache {
    private static HashMap<Integer, Object> cache = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
    ...
```

Подскажите решение по-лучше)

Comment: Если вы исправляете грамматические ошибки, исправляйте без ошибок!!

Answer (score 1):

У хибернейта есть готовое решение в виде second level cashe. Советую вам посмотреть в его сторону

Comment: нет, спасибо. Не хочу его использовать

Comment: Почему нет? Почему бы не попытаться использовать стандартное решение, а не изобретать велосипед? Я не знаю как в hibernate, но кэш в Oracle TopLink вполне прилично работает.

Comment: Кэш должнен быть прозрачным, т.е. написан самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [SoftReference Caching](http://www.fromdev.com/2008/09/building-faster-and-efficient-cache.html)